What's the real life uses of Reflexive Closure in computer science?
I was tasked to discuss Reflexive Closure, in relation to computer science. In Discrete Mathematics context, its basically a set that relates to an element itself. But I just can't find any explanation about its uses in real world, and its application in computer science. If you could explain, or drop an article or link. That would be a big help. Thank you
I have searched the internet. But only find the definition of it. None real life uses.

(First: are you sure the assignment is not about transitive reflexive closure?)
I think you're correct in observing that taking the reflexive closure of a relation rarely happens, and it's hard to come up with natural examples.
In mathematics, definitions are only introduced when they help simplify the resulting description. Introducing the transitive or transitive reflexive closure of a relation can be very helpful, when it avoids a more complex iterative or recursive definition. For instance, when reasoning about trees, it can be helpful to reason about a node's descendants, and descendants can be defined using the transitive closure of the tree's parent-child relation. So transitive closure can really help simplify the resulting mathematical statements.
This is rarely the case for reflexive closure. It doesn't do much, so its use will not simplify the resulting mathematical statements by very much; the cost of its introduction will usually be higher than the benefits.
We can also sense this by looking at notation: transitive closure ($R^+$) and transitive reflexive closure ($R^*$) have a dedicated notation; reflexive closure is just $R \cup I$ (where $I$ is the identity relation) so introducing a separate notation for it just isn't worth it. Similarly, introducing the reflexive closure itself is rarely worth it.
Whether your professor is interested in any of this is anybody's guess, but in your place, I would argue along these lines.
